# Fill the blank data with available data in the same dimension field in the Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to create a new calculated field by filling the (`Dimension 3`) blanks with available data (`Dimension 3`) by using the (`Dimension 1`). Currently I'm doing manual correction in input files, it's a repeatable correction when doing refreshing in the Tableau. Below is the scenario which I'm working.

Current scenario:

```
Dimension1|Dimension2|Dimension3
String1   |1         |Text1
String2   |2         |Text2
String2   |3
String3   |4         |Text3
String4   |5
String4   |6         |Text4
```

Requirement scenario:

```
Dimension1|Dimension2|Dimension3
String1   |1         |Text1
String2   |2         |Text2
String2   |3         |Text2
String3   |4         |Text3
String4   |5         |Text4
String4   |6         |Text4
```

Comment: Can there be a scenario when for a given string in Dimension1 there are two different text values as well as at least one blank value? If yes, what will be fill_up value? If no, that may probably be worked.

Comment: If the two questions aren't different, please delete one.

Comment: By the way, since I know tableau doesn't allow data correction/entry, please let me know where you manage/wrangle your data?

Comment: It has only one-to-one mapping. here in this case, one is blank and other is Text value for respective string. I require to fill the BLANK with available text value for respective string. I'm managing the data in Excel file.

Comment: Ok. I got it.  If you are managing your data in Excel,  it is way too easy to fill up blank values there itself.  I will try to give you both solutions after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot alter data in tableau you have to create a new filed which you can use instead of this `Dimension3`.  Do it like this

Add a calculated field `Dim3_calculated` as

```
IFNULL([Dimension3], {FIXED [Dimension1]: MIN([Dimension3])})
```

And use this calculated field instead of `Dimension3` in your calculation.

You're done.  Do tell if it worked.

[image]

Comment: As I said, it is still much easier to do in `Excel` directly